# SwiftUI. Access custom view subviews from custom view modifier

Tags: ios, swiftui, viewmodifier

I have a custom view:

```
public struct CustomView: View {
    var text1: String
    var text2: String

    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text1).tag(0)
            Text(text2).tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create view modifier and pass custom Style parameter to it:

```
struct Watermark: ViewModifier {
    var style: Style

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
          if style == .one {
              // access Text with tag 0 and set foreground color to red
              // access Text with tag 1 and set foreground color to blue
          } else if style == .two {
              // access Text with tag 0 and set foreground color to black
              // access Text with tag 1 and set foreground color to pink
          }
}
```

How to access content child view from Modifier to change it style ?

I would like to do something similar as apple do with SF Image

[image]

P.S.: I want to use exactly view modifier. I don't want to pass Style as parameter to view. Because I want to build complex custom views where it can be more then 7 parameters. And I don't want to pass 7 parameters to view initialiser. View modifiers looks more nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `tag` for identifying views. `tag` is very hard to read. The view trait key for it is an internal type, so you'd need to use `Mirror`.

You can use the environment instead. Create an environment key for each of the 7+ parameters you will have.

In this case, there are 2 colors, so I'll create 2 keys. If there are more colors, I'd instead use one key that has an array as a value.

```
struct Color1Key: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue = AnyShapeStyle(.primary)
}

struct Color2Key: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue = AnyShapeStyle(.secondary)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var color1: AnyShapeStyle {
        get { self[Color1Key.self] }
        set { self[Color1Key.self] = newValue }
    }
    var color2: AnyShapeStyle {
        get { self[Color2Key.self] }
        set { self[Color2Key.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Instead of `tag`, write your own view modifiers that read from the environment.

```
struct Color1Modifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.color1) var color1
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.foregroundStyle(color1)
    }
}

struct Color2Modifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.color2) var color2
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.foregroundStyle(color2)
    }
}

extension View {
    func color1() -> some View {
        modifier(Color1Modifier())
    }
    func color2() -> some View {
        modifier(Color2Modifier())
    }
}

// usage:
VStack {
    Text(text1).color1()
    Text(text2).color2()
}
.modifier(Watermark(style: ...))
```

Then `Watermark` can write to the environment:

```
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .environment(\.color1, AnyShapeStyle(style == .one ? .red : .black))
        .environment(\.color2, AnyShapeStyle(style == .one ? .blue : .pink))
}
```

---

Here is an implementation of the same idea but with one environment key holding an array of color styles:

```
struct CustomView: View {
    var text1: String
    var text2: String
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text1).color(0)
            Text(text2).color(1)
        }
        .modifier(Watermark(style: ...))
    }
}

struct ColorsModifier: ViewModifier {
    let index: Int
    
    @Environment(\.colors) var colors
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.foregroundStyle(
            colors.indices.contains(index) ? colors[index] : AnyShapeStyle(.opacity(1))
        )
    }
}

extension View {
    func color(_ n: Int) -> some View {
        modifier(ColorsModifier(index: n))
    }
}

struct ColorsKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: [AnyShapeStyle] = []
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var colors: [AnyShapeStyle] {
        get { self[ColorsKey.self] }
        set { self[ColorsKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct Watermark: ViewModifier {
    enum Style {
        case one, two
    }
    
    var style: Style
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(
                \.colors,
                style == .one ?
                 [.init(.red), .init(.blue)] :
                 [.init(.black), .init(.pink)]
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve something similar would be to pass both the `style` and the `tag` to the `ViewModifier`. These are read-only, so they don't even need to be a `Binding`:

```swift
enum Style {
    case one
    case two
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var style = Style.one

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            CustomView(
                text1: "The quick brown fox",
                text2: "jumps over the lazy dog",
                style: style
            )
            Picker("Style", selection: $style) {
                Text("One").tag(Style.one)
                Text("Two").tag(Style.two)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .fixedSize()
        }
    }
}

struct Watermark: ViewModifier {
    let tag: Int
    let style: Style

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        switch style {
        case .one:
            switch tag {
            case 0: content.foregroundStyle(.red)
            case 1: content.foregroundStyle(.blue)
            default: content
            }
        case .two:
            switch tag {
            case 0: content.foregroundStyle(.black)
            case 1: content.foregroundStyle(.pink)
            default: content
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct CustomView: View {
    let text1: String
    let text2: String
    let style: Style

    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text1)
                .modifier(Watermark(tag: 0, style: style))
            Text(text2).tag(1)
                .modifier(Watermark(tag: 1, style: style))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Answer updated: the `ViewModifier` doesn't need to be passed any Bindings because the values are read-only